# github: "Updates were rejected because tip of your current branch is behind"How do i fix it?

Tags: github

well i have been pushing my files on heroku like (git push heroku master) and everything is fine in there.Now i have created new repo in github and i want to push everyfiles just like in heroku but it gives me error saying "updates were rejected because your working branch is behind".How can i push all of the files which is locally to newly created git repository?

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: on branch master nothing to commit,working tree clean

Comment: After a `git fetch`? I'm expecting a different message. Please add the status to your question, not as a comment!

Comment: there is no error after running git fetch.How do i add status?Sorry i am new here.

Comment: Please add the following output to your question: `git remote -v`, `git fetch`, `git status`

Comment: finally i fixed it thanks for your time though i had to run: git rebase origin/master

Comment: So please delete the question as you were not willing to provide the information needed to provide an answer. As it is now, the question cannot help anybody.